# WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-context

First, I am sorry for posting this issue again, I see this error posted here on Stackoverflow multiple-times. Unfortunately seems, this error is fired from various reasons and reading answers gave me no solution. I will try describe my problem in details and based on questions/answers in other posts.

I use two Activities in my application. First activity is main menu. Pressing menu item finishes first activity (firstActivity.finish()) and starts second activity with intent. If I am done in second activity then I  finish it (secondActivity.finish()) and I start first activity with intent (I return back to menu).

I really need to have only one instance of currently started activity. So, both activities use android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest.

In my application I use library what has public class called "Global" and I extend this class to AppGlobal in my application. "Global" class has static field context :

```
 class Global {    
    public static Context context;   
 }

 class AppGlobal extends Global {
 }
```

In create method of each Activity I update context with activity instance - "this".

```
 public class FirstActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        AppGlobal.context = this;
   }
}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        AppGlobal.context = this;
   }
}
```

Later, in second activity I detect "back" button and on key UP event I want show dialog.

```
public class Video extends GLSurfaceView {
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getRepeatCount() > 0) {
             return true;
        }
        return EmuManager.onHandleKey(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getRepeatCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return Manager.onHandleKey(keyCode, event);
    }
}

class Manager {
   public static boolean onHandleKey(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event)
   {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          SettingsDialog d = new SettingsDialog();
          d.show(); 
       }
       return true;
   }
}
```

SettingDialog needs context and I supply it in constructor:

```
public class SettingsDialog extends Dialog {    
     public SettingsDialog() {
           super(AppGlobal.context); 
     }
}
```

I never experienced it, but in logs from google developer console I see it crashes sometimes on "**d.show()**" in onHandleKey :

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@3d2d4e99 is not valid; is your activity
>   running?  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:711)
>     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
>     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:312) ...

This crash is very rare, but it happens. It still appears from time to time in logs. I checked thread IDs, but dialog is shown on main thread. Seems like a AppGlobal.context problem.

Experienced someone something like this? Can I store context this way?

Comment: before moving to different activity make sure to dismiss your dialogs.
thats caused the windowmanager$badtokenExepction or passing a destroyed context to a dialog.

Comment: Yes, I will write routine for destroying all dialogs on activity finish. Thanks for idea. But, I run command "AppGlobal.context=this" in onCreate of each activity (so context should be always actual). And from log I see it crashed when user pressed back button in second activity and the settings dialog tried to show.

Comment: To be more detailed...main menu is library and second activity is book. In main menu is possible create shortcut to every book at home screen. Then I can start book directly from home screen without going to application main menu. In the background happens this : launcher starts activity1 with intent and ID parameter of the book. In onCreate of 1st activity  I update context. Then I read intent's ID parameter. If is ID null(or empty string) then I continue with starting main menu. Else I finish 1st activity and I start second activity(book)with intent. Can be context broken during these steps?

Comment: yes, i think whats happening is the global context is not updating.
let say the second activity runs and change the globalContext to 2nd activity. and when backpress called, the setting dialog is use 2nd but actually it was destroyed. 

maybe you can add context parameter to your settings dialog.

Comment: Or maybe I can update AppGlobal.context in onResume of Activity?